# Cannot correctly document macro with doxygen

Tags: c++, ubuntu, doxygen

I'm using `ubuntu 12.10 bundled doxygen` version for documenting a c++ source code base.

I'm encountering a problem with a macro (only one, but not the others). The problematic macro is defined exactly this:

```
   #define MYNS_ENFORCE(cond, ex) \
   if (!(cond)) throw ex
```

`Doxygen` works well with other macros. What it does with the other macros is to list in a MACROS section something like this:

```
   #define MY_MACRO(param)
```

And later, in the detailed section, it lists the `macro` expansion value.

But for the problematic macro it lists something like this:

```
   #define MYNS_ENFORCE(cond, ex) 
   if (!(cond)) throw ex
```

All in the brief section and nothing for the detailed section. I tried to search but I found no example similar to this.

My configuration for the macro expansion is the following one:

```
   ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES

   MACRO_EXPANSION        = YES

   EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = YES
```

Could anyone give a hint or solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: version of doxygen using. Kindly use the latest